# Unable to move sprite left or right in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

https://github.com/bmh3110/JackTheGiantGame

I'm unable to move my sprite left or right when the screen is touched. I'm just starting this game and I can't even get it to work. I've had this problem for a few days and it's getting really frustrating.

GameplayScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene {
    var player : Player?
    var canMove = false
    var moveLeft = false
    var center : CGFloat?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        center = (self.scene?.size.width)! / (self.scene?.size.height)!
        player = self.childNodeWithName("Player") as? Player!
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        managePlayer()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if location.x > center {
                moveLeft = false
            } else {
                moveLeft = true
            }
        }

        canMove = true
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }

    func managePlayer() {
        if canMove {
            player?.movePlayer(moveLeft)
        }
    }
}
```

Player.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    func movePlayer(moveLeft: Bool) {
        if moveLeft {
            self.position.x = self.position.x - 7
        } else {
            self.position.x = self.position.x + 7 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the relative code here.

Comment: Make sure that the 'player' custom class in the inspector is the Player class.

Comment: @Abdou023 Yes the class name for the Player Sprite does have the player class name. It's JackTheGiantGame.Player

Answer (score 0):

In the `touchesEnded` function set `canMove = false`